# Control para mostrar Cursor con buscador android

Tags: java, android

Tengo en mi aplicación una parte donde el usuario debe seleccionar un contacto de la lista de contactos, ya pude y logré traerme la lista junto con el teléfono, como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto de aquí es un spinner, con un CURSOR como fuente de datos, mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿cómo podría agregarle un buscador en este spinner?

mi código hasta ahora es

```
 Spinner imgpayment = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.imgpayment);



        Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Data._ID, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND "
                        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL", null,
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        startManagingCursor(mCursor);


        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                mCursor, // cursor
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER }, // cursor

                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }

        );
        imgpayment.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ya intente usar el SpinnerDialog que encontre investigando  y me aparece asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta acá todo perfecto, pero no puedo  hacer que muestre el nombre y el número, solo puedo elegir una de las 2 y es inviable,  el código de la segunda imagen es

```
   ArrayList<String> contactos = new ArrayList<String>();
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            contactos.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("DISPLAY_NAME"))); //add the item
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }


        spinner = new SpinnerDialog(this,contactos,"Elegir Contacto",3);
        spinner.bindOnSpinerListener(new OnSpinerItemClick() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(String s, int i) {
                String a = s ;
                String b = s ;

            }
        });

        btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bottton);

        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                spinner.showSpinerDialog();
            }
        });
```

¿cómo podría al primero agregarle un filtrado?

Comment: Es que creo que lo que intentas realizar no se si se puede. Si entiendo bien la cuestión sería tener un buscador en el propio spinner pero para eso esta la 2 opción que mencionas.... no?

Comment: Al parecer el objeto `SpinnerDialog` no acepta más que un arreglo de String. Checa a ver si es opción poner el número junto al nombre, por ejemplo "Prueba2 - 12345", así podrías tener el número también y sería buscable, inclusive, intenta poner algo como "Prueba2\n12345" a ver si lo pone en otra línea o "Prueba2<br />12345", aunque no sé si este último sea válido.

Comment: Bruno, lo que deseas es que al escribir una palabra te muestre resultados similares? @BrunoSosaFastTag

Comment: gracias a todos aunque ya esta resuelta  , al final le encontre la vuelta estoy esperando los dias para ponerla como resuelta

Comment: Que usaste para realizar esto? veo que no usaste un Autocomplete que sería lo adecuado.

Comment: Jorge , gracias por la buena onda y la dedicacion y la calidad en la que das respuestas , este defecto lo explique mejor en esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111995/filtro-android-studio-listview-con-adapter-perzonalizado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este incoveniente fue resuelto tal y como lo explica esta pregunta ,
[Filtro Android Studio , ListView Con adapter Perzonalizado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111995/filtro-android-studio-listview-con-adapter-perzonalizado)

Dentro del adaptador crea un método que filtre los datos de acuerdo al texto ingresado por el usuario. Luego simplemente llamas ese método desde tu Dialog y le pasas el texto que ingrese el usuario.

Tu adaptador debe quedar así:

```
class AdapterMostrarContactos extends BaseAdapter {

protected Activity activity ;
ArrayList<Contacto> contactos;
ArrayList<Contacto> copyContactos = new ArrayList<>();

public AdapterMostrarContactos(Activity activity,  ArrayList<Contacto> contactos){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.contactos = contactos;
    this.copyContactos.addAll(contactos); // Crea una copia de los contactos
}

...

/* Filtra los datos del adaptador */
public void filtrar(String texto) {

    // Elimina todos los datos del ArrayList que se cargan en los
    // elementos del adaptador
    contactos.clear();

    // Si no hay texto: agrega de nuevo los datos del ArrayList copiado
    // al ArrayList que se carga en los elementos del adaptador
    if (texto.length() == 0) {
        contactos.addAll(copyContactos);
    } else {

        // Recorre todos los elementos que contiene el ArrayList copiado
        // y dependiendo de si estos contienen el texto ingresado por el
        // usuario los agrega de nuevo al ArrayList que se carga en los 
        // elementos del adaptador.
        for (Contacto contacto : copyContactos) {

            if (contacto.getNombre().contains(texto)) {
                contactos.add(contacto);
            }
        }
    }
```

En tu clase ContactsListDialog llamas el método filtrar.

public class ContactsListDialog extends Dialog implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener  {

```
...

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
      adapter.filtrar(filterText.getText().toString());
    }

};
```

}